# Manipulating sparse matrices in Matlab

Tags: matlab, indexing, block, sparse-matrix

Suppose I have a sparse matrix `Sparstica` that is a vertical concatenation of several other sparse matrices. When I type `Sparstica(:)`, I get a list of the nonzero elements. In the left column, will be the index of the element, in the right column will be the nonzero element.

How can I manipulate the i-th and j-th non-zero element of every other sparse block matrix in the middle `n-2` blocks (`n` sparse block matrices in total)?

---

**Appended**: To clarify what I mean by the i-th and j-th element of every other sparse matrix, suppose I have

> Sparstica = [A_1; A_2; A_3; ... ; A_n]

This was created from `vertcat`. Now I need to take the i-th and j-th, say the 3rd and 5th,  nonzero element of *every other* sparse matrix from `A_2` to `A_{N-1}` (I know the notation for this actually isn't allowed, but just for demonstrative purposes). I'd like to accomplish this *without* using for-loops if possible.

Comment: How large is `n` in your case? And have you checked that using `for`-loops is definitely too slow?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/accessing-sparse-matrices.html#f6-9348 ctrl+f "exacerbate the inefficiency". For my purposes `n` can reach upwards of 2^15 or so. I forget what the upper limit is that Matlab can handle on my machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the non-zero elements using `find`:

```
>> A = speye(3)

A =

   (1,1)        1
   (2,2)        1
   (3,3)        1

>> I = find(A ~= 0)

I =

     1
     5
     9
```

If you need the indices in row/column format, use `ind2sub`:

```
>> [X, Y] = ind2sub(size(A), I)

X =

     1
     2
     3

Y =

     1
     2
     3
```

Comment: Do you know how I could manipulate the same i-th and j-th element of every other sparse matrix without using a for loop?

Comment: Can you clearify what you mean with "the same i-th and j-th element of every other sparse matrix"?

Comment: I thought about this for a bit, but I couldn't come up with something that doesn't use `for` loops. If this is critical for your code and if standard MATLAB `for` loops are too slow then I suggest either performing these operations before the big sparse matrix is assembled or using a MEX-function to perform the looping.

Comment: Side note on `find`: requesting two outputs yields row-column directly, e.g., `[X,Y]=find(A)` yields `X=[1;2;3],Y=[1;2;3]` in place of `ind2sub(size(A),find(A))`.  Third output gives you value also; see [MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) or [GNU Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Finding-Elements-and-Checking-Conditions.html) docs for more.